# `npx create-react-app my-app` is trying to use the wrong npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm using a MacBook Pro.

I have a fresh install of `nvm`. I set the node version and it's set to 16.17.0 and `npm -v` and `nix -v` both show 8.15.0.

When I run `npx create-react-app my-app` it fails and the log shows the following...

```
info using npm@6.5.0
```

Where is this coming from, and how do I fix it?

I originally installed a number of recent and not-so-recent versions of node.js with Homebrew and I had the exact same error. I completely annihilated every instance of node.js and npm from /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin. There is nothing related in my `$PATH`, but there must be a reference somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I played around and discovered that installing version 14.0.0 of node.js plays nicely and my app is now created... but I am now getting...

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.0.0
```

I'm still confounded by the original error because I also tried with 12.0.0 and it tried to work and failed in a nice manner with an error that I could play along with. I'm still baffled by the original error.